# Why is my PHP timestamp two hours short?

Tags: php

Code:

```
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $textDate = strtotime($date);
    var_dump($textDate);
    var_dump($date);
```

The output:

```
int 1352012400
string '11/04/12' (length=8)
```

The issue is that when you convert the actual timestamp out, it's 1AM EST.

I'm generating this timestamp having set the timezone to PST -- what is going on?  What am I doing wrong?  I can obviously just add two hours, but I really shouldn't have to!  This can't be a result of timestamp issues with my server or PC, either, because this is happening in abeyance of current time -- I'm converting a date from a specific format to the UNIX timestamp for midnight in the morning, that date.

Comment: How do you check timestamp is wrong? `var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $textDate));`

Comment: Can you make it clear? What is `$date`?

Comment: EST!=PST ? this should be issue :)

Comment: date +%s -d '11/04/12 00:00 PST' :1352016000

Comment: date +%s -d '11/04/12 00:00 PDT':1352012400
Los Angeles is PDT

Comment: @zerkms I used http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php to convert it to a readable format.  Using your method to check it, it comes out right..  So I have no clue why the time stamp that later gets uploaded into the DB is offset by the same two hours.  I'll check it again, the error is probably somewhere else then.

Comment: @AlvinWong 'date' is a user input variable that's guaranteed to have the format of dd/dd/dd -- MM/DD/YY assumed, but I may not be properly enforcing that.

Comment: @RonLugge: that happens because timestamp doesn't store timezone. It's just a number of seconds passed since unix epoch. It's continuous and exactly the same for all timezones.

Comment: @zerkms I actually know that, which is why I was surprised that I was getting a 1AM time for EST, when I thought I'd defined midnight PST.  (Three hour difference).  Turns out that today was the end of DST -- that's why all my math was screwball and couldn't come out with the same answer twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual issue appears to have revolved around the use of DST -- because the date in question was at the end of DST, time calculations became skewed by about one hour.  How that turned what should have been 3AM EST into 1AM EST I'm not sure (perhaps the website I used to do the quickie conversion was off), but it also explains why all my math was coming out wrong no matter how many times I checked it.